# How to change data in one collection, so that other data, that is saved in the same collection will be changed as well?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs, mongoose-schema

I have one mongoose schema called workshop.
[workshop schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/souZg.png)

The session schema is nested inside the workshop schema.
[session schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaiMv.png)

What I need to do: 
When I add/subtract in one session, the other session should be updated to the accurate time.

For example:
Session A: 60 minutes
Session B: 45 minutes

When I edit session A, and change the number from 60 to 55 minutes, I need the time in session B to automatically be updated to 50 minutes.

Furthermore, if I have session C, the 5 minutes from session A should divide between session B and C.
[edit session route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JU4R.png)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you are updating the values, how many can you update at the same time and what is the logic for 3 values (if i remove 10 from B, will A and C earn 5 each?).

You can either perform the logic in the route or you can use a mongoose middleware with the help of a custom field and a setter for the time:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/getters-setters.html

ex:

```
Session.path("time", function(value) {
this._oldTime = this.time;
return value;
})

Workshop.pre("save", function() {
  Session.findById(this._id).populate("sessions").exec((err, workshop) => {

   // your calculation here. Compare this._oldValue in each session document of the workshop, see what changes and calculate what needs to be done to change the others sessions values, then save each.
  })
})
```